# How to validate unique tel in array values when update multiple records

Tags: php, laravel, validation

When updating multiple records , I need to check `tel` field is `unique` (except id's tel).

I know to use this to validate specified `id`

```
'tel' => 'unique:dtb_users,tel,'.$user->id
```

but multiple is not

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'tel.*' => [
        'nullable',
        'min:10',
        'max:12',
        'unique:dtb_users,tel' <- stuck here
    ]
]);
```

My form has more fields , here is two of those(in `foreach` loop)

```
<div class="form-group form-group-user form-user-table mb-1">
    <input id="email_{{$user->id}}" name="email[{{$user->id}}]" type="email" data-id="{{ $user->id }}" class="form-control email-validation text-color{{ $errors->has("email.$user->id") ? ' is-invalid' : '' }} input_change" value="{{ $old['email'][$user->id] ?? $user->email }}" placeholder="{{__('user.email_placeholder')}}" disabled>
    @if ($errors->has("email.$user->id"))
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first("email.$user->id") }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group-user form-user-table mb-0 number">
    <input id="tel_{{ $user->id }}" name="tel[{{ $user->id }}]" class="form-control tel-validation text-color{{ $errors->has('tel.' . $user->id) ? ' is-invalid' : '' }} input_change only-numbers" value="{{ $old['tel'][$user->id] ?? $user->tel }}" placeholder="00000000000" disabled>
    @if ($errors->has("tel.$user->id"))
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first("tel.$user->id") }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
```

I'm pulling my hair out , any idea is respected . Thanks for all !

`Answer`

```
'unique:dtb_users,tel' -> Rule::unique('dtb_users', 'tel')->ignore(*)
```

Comment: Is each `tel` associated with the same `User` or is each `tel` associated with a different `User`?

Comment: each tel is associated with a different user

Comment: Can you add the code for your `form` to your question as that will help.

Comment: I modified my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with an adjustment to how you're naming the `input` elements of your `form`, the following should work.

In your blade file, change the value of the `name` attribute to follow the format:

```
name="users[{{ $user->id }}][field]"
```

So;

```
<input id="tel_{{ $user->id }}" name="users[{{ $user->id }}][tel]"
    class="form-control tel-validation text-color{{ $errors->has('tel.' . $user->id) ? ' is-invalid' : '' }} input_change only-numbers"
    value="{{ $old['tel'][$user->id] ?? $user->tel }}"
    placeholder="00000000000"
    readonly />
```

Then in your controller action, update your validation rules to as follows:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'users' => ['required', 'array'],
    'users.*.tel' => [
        'nullable',
        'min:10',
        'max:12',
        Rule::unique('users', 'tel')->ignore('*'),
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer , I use your rule ```Rule::unique('users', 'tel')->ignore('*')```, don't change anything and it works

Answer (score 0):

I remember back in 2-3 years I struggled a lot with this too.
Here is the answer:

```
'tel' => 'unique:dtb_users,tel,'. $this->id .''
```

`$this->id` is the record you are trying to update. If it doesn't find it like that you can put `request()->route()->parameter('paramName');`

`paramName` is the one you declared in the route;

Comment: No , your rule is only validate a record . My data is array

Comment: try         Rule::unique('unique:dtb_users')->ignore($record->id),

Answer (score 0):

This way is working

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'tel.*' => [
        'nullable',
        'min:10',
        'max:12',
        new UserTelUniqueRule($request->all('id', 'tel'))
    ]
]);
```

In `UserTelUniqueRule`

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use App\Models\DtbUsers;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class UserTelUnique implements Rule
{
    /**
     * @param array $input
     */
    protected $input;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     * @param array $input
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($input)
    {
        $this->input = $input;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        foreach ($this->input['id'] as $id) {
            $tel = $this->input['tel'][$id];
            if (is_null($tel)) {
                continue;
            }
            $user = DtbUsers::where('tel', $tel)
                            ->where('id', '!=', $id)
                            ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                            ->first();
            if ($user) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return __('validation.unique');
    }
}
```